# what table structure will give faster sql query results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, optimization

i want to make a table that will reflect an actions of user to another user in my application.

i have in mind two solutions , i want to know what will be faster ?

1)

```
ID | source_user_id | target_user_id | action_type
```

in this option i will create a row for each action

2)

```
Id | source_user_id | target_user_id | action_x | action_y | action_z
```

in this option i will create a row for all actions available with other user, 
when action is not performed the field will be set to NULL value 
this row will be created only if at least one action was performed

can u also help me understand why the best choice will be

excuse me for my bad English . 
thank you

Comment: The main problem is that you don't know how to measure this by yourself. I don't know mysql but I can imagine oodles of ways to do performance testing. One possible and simple solution would be do ask google. However, from my point of view: #2 is faster as it avoids a `JOIN`. But is is a very stupid way of designing a table structure as it violates with the 3ND as far as I can remember.

Comment: The main problem is sacrificing correctness for performance. Speed kills. The need for speed kills even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be faster for what?

For getting all the actions for a particular user, then the second solution should be faster, although this might be by only a small amount.

For adding a new action in, the first solution is much, much, much faster.  The second solution requires re-organizing the table.

Next, you don't say what you are putting into the column for the second case.  If you are putting in strings that are 2,000 characters long, then the first case may be much faster, especially with the suggestion by hellohellosharp of using ids instead of values.  The shorter records and reduced I/O should make up for having to join a big table to a small reference table.

Because you do not give enough information to actually answer your question about performance, the best answer is to focus on database design.  For this, an action table should probably have an auto-incrementing id, two user ids, an action id, and a date/time field for when it occurred.  With the appropriate indexes, getting information about a particular user or user/action should have sufficiently good performance for your application.

Comment: you explain all the possible scenario , i was warried about selection and joining from my users table, since this will happend more ,i will put a date in action_x, action_y, action_z

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not number two. I would go with a modified number one:

```
ID | source_user_id | target_user_id | **action_id**
```

Then make a table `actions`

```
ID | action_type | action_info | etc
```

This will allow you to make multiple different actions and is a lot more flexible. You said, "i will create a row for all actions available with other user"...but, according to your layout, what you really meant is you will create another *column* for each action available between users. That is a very bad way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Before defining your tables structure, you first have to decide **which of your expected queries are performance-critical?** Is it *get all available `action`s for `source` and `target user`*? Or is it *get how many `action_type`s are currently available in your system*? The way the tables should be built may tremendously vary accordingly.

After that is well-determined, you can use many technics for building tables that are optimized for your needs, such as:

1. Embed data-units that are usually retrieved together in the same table;
2. Index columns;
3. Many many more of which the first two here are the most basic.

Comment: my main action will be getting what actions i have performed on other users when i am searching for users , and to list the users i have performed actions on .